# loop to delete table rows through numerous worksheets based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, row, listobject

working on a loop to delete stock info from numerous worksheets in a workbook. Each sheet is named, "Client_ClientFirstName", and each table in each worksheet is the same as the worksheet name. here is the code ive come up with so far, any and all advice is appreciated.

```
Sub RemoveTickerFromAccounts()

Dim Client As Worksheet
Dim varTickerToFind As String
varTickerToFind = Worksheets("Entry").Cells(5, 1)


Dim tblSearchTable As Range

For Each Client In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If InStr(1, Client.Name, "Client_", vbTextCompare) Then
            'ws.Range("B30").Select
            Worksheets(Client.Name).Activate
            'tblSearchTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

            ActiveSheet.Range("b30").Select
            If Selection.ListObject.Name = Client.Name Then
            'tblSearchTable = "Table14"


            'tblSearchTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Client.Name).Select

        For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Client.Name).ListRows.Count
            If ActiveSheet.ListObject.ListRows(i, 1).Value = varTickerToFind _
                Then
                tblSearchTable.ListRows(i).Delete

                Exit For
            Else
                MsgBox "Unable to Find Ticker"
                Exit For
            End If

        Next i
        End If
    End If
 Next Client


End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Is there one?

Comment: @Tim Williams yeah it breaks down when i try to set tblSearchTable= Client.Name, and I've tried messing around by changing tblSearchTable to a range instead of a list object. I think the errors mainly have to do with the slightly different properties available to list objects.

Comment: If the listobject has the same name as the worksheet do you really need to check that?  You can just use `Client.ListObjects(1)` (*without* activating the worksheet) as long as there's just one listobject.

Comment: @Tim Williams ok got that part working, I was using a faulty demo workbook. it breaks down at   If ActiveSheet.ListObject.ListRows(i, 1).Value = varTickerToFind _then. I think it has to do with .value not being a property of ListRows, but is there another that I could use to isolate that value in the first column of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested:

```
Sub RemoveTickerFromAccounts()

Dim Client As Worksheet
Dim varTickerToFind As String
Dim tblSearch As ListObject
Dim bFound As Boolean, i As Long

    varTickerToFind = Worksheets("Entry").Cells(5, 1).Value

    For Each Client In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Client.Name Like "Client_*" Then

            Set tblSearch = Client.ListObjects(1)

            For i = 1 To tblSearch.ListRows.Count
                If tblSearch.ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1).Value = varTickerToFind Then
                    tblSearch.ListRows(i).Delete
                    bFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

            If Not bFound Then 
                MsgBox "Unable to Find Ticker '" & varTickerToFind & "'"
            End If
        End If

     Next Client
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly. Just because I am still new to VBA, what does the Boolean/bFound variable do?

Comment: It's used as a "flag" to capture the fact that the row was found and deleted.  In your original code (absent the other issues) you would have seen a message for every table row until the ticker was located.